# Exporting to pdf in QGIS 2.8 composer does not respect line styles

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pdf

I'm using QGIS 2.8. When I export a map using "export to pdf" in Composer, the style of lines of my vector data in the resulting pdf file is not what is seen on the screen. When I export to jpeg it does not do this and lines are correctly displayed. Here are two screenshots: the first is how my map should look like (exporting to jpg); the second is how the maps comes out when I export it to pdf. The style I defined for the contour lines is not respected when I export to pdf (I get thicker lines and all the same).

[image: This is how my map should look like; different widths of contour lines]
[image: This is how my map looks like when I export it to pdf; the same thick width on all contour lines]

Answer (score -1):

you must lower the oppacity of the layer, then the lines will print fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).